# Why is declaring a std::ifstream called cin not a compilation error?

Tags: c++, ifstream, istream, ambiguous

Recently, I was curious as to what would happen if I declared a `std::ifstream` called `cin`, then tried to read input with it. I thought that this would result in a compilation error, because the compiler wouldn't be able to differentiate whether to use the `std::istream` or the `std::ifstream` for the input operation. Here's the code I wrote to test this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream cin("math_testprogram.in");

    int N;
    cin >> N; // I expect this line to result in some sort of
              // "reference to cin is ambiguous" error

    cout << N << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The current code (on my compiler, at least) tries to read `N` from the file instead of standard input. If I change the `cin >> N` line to `std::cin >> N`, however, then the program starts trying to read `N` from standard input (as expected).

My question is, why doesn't the compiler give an error in this case (the compiler I compiled this program with is GCC 7.5.0)? Is there some other misconception that I'm making here?

Comment: Local variables always take precedence over globals, right?  So the code is perfectly legal.  I guess it's a little surprising that `-Wshadow` doesn't warn about it, though.

Comment: I am pretty sure `-Wshadow` would warn about that. "Turn you compiler warnings on" is probably the best and least followed advice.

Comment: @spectras gcc doesn't; clang does:  https://godbolt.org/z/1K7hMe

Comment: Slightly related: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same identifier can be used for different variables:

- in different namespaces, and
- inside a code block, with the inner scope overruling the outer scope.

In your code you do both of these things. The global object called `std::cin` and the local object of `main` function called `cin` can coexist with no problem.

A name declared in a code block hides the same name from a more outer scope. After you have declared your own `cin`, then you would need to write `std::cin` to get that one.